# How do I erase unwanted line on the bottom of the tabbar in android

Tags: android, tabs, tabbar

I adapted drawable image on the background of each tab but,

they doesn't stretch to boundary.

there stay gray color line on bottom of the tabs. How can I erase this gray line in tab?

It seems basic tab's bottom attribute.

Comment: I tried..  But  my reputation is below 10

Comment: Which API is this for? Is this tab on an Action bar?

Comment: @user1433078 Did you solve it? I am facing same issue.